# PC cannot connect to internet using new cable modem

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, router, modem

I got a new 2 port cable modem to replace the single port one that died recently.  The Windows laptop connects to the internet fine, but the desktop PC running Xubuntu 20.04.6 LTS cannot get a network connection with the new modem.  Tried different ports on the modem and swapping cables.  The modem is not WiFi capable.  In Network Connections, the settings are as follows:

General tab

- Connect automatically with priority 1 checked
- All users may connect to this network checked

Ethernet tab

- Device enp3s0 (ethernet card mac address)
- MTU automatic
- Wake on LAN - Default is checked
- Link negotiation is Automatic

IPv4 Settings

- Automatic (DHCP)

IPv6 Settings

- Automatic

Contents of `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`

```
#Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Contents of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`nmcli connection show` brings up both connection names (one is old and not used), the UUID for both, Type as Ethernet for both, and enp3s0 as Device for Connection 2

`nmcli general` has State as disconnected, Connectivity as none, and all others as enabled

`ip link show` brings up the following for enp3s0:

```
<BROADCAST,MULITCAST,UP,LOWER,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether [ethernet card mac address] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Do I need to enter the MAC address for the cable modem anywhere?

I've been tinkering with this for over a month, so any suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT**

As per the comment and reply below, the cable modem I have is not also a router.  It seems that only one MAC address is allowed to access the internet via the modem, even though it has two ports for two PCs.  A router with NAT (network address translation) would likely be needed to use both at the same time.  Or use a router to clone the MAC address of the laptop.  What I am going to do as a sort of workaround is enter the MAC address of the laptop into the cloned MAC address section of my connection's network manager settings on the linux PC, and make sure the Windows laptop is not connected to the internet while using the linux PC. I don't need both online at the same time anyway.  Thank you all for the responses.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager`. Look at the current ststus with `service NetworkManager status`. Read ` man service`.

Comment: Do you have two systems connected directly to the modem?  Do you know if the modem is also a router and switch?  Most cable modems are not and are only capable of 1 MAC address for connecting to the internet.  You might need a router that will allow you to clone the MAC of the system that is working so that the connection can be routed to all systems on your network.

Comment: @Terrance Yes, there are 2 systems connected to the 2 ports on the modem.  You are correct in assuming that the modem is not also a router.  I got the linux PC to access the internet by cloning the mac address for the laptop, and making sure the laptop is not on (or at least not connected to the internet) while using the linux PC.  I don't need them both online at the same time anyway, so that will be the fix I am using.  Thank you Terrance and vidarlo for the information, I would never have figured it out on my own!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ISP only gives you one IP, even though your modem has multiple ports.

You need a router that can provide NAT functionality so that additional systems can connect.

You either need a router that supports cloning MAC from the Windows PC, or wait for the lease from the ISP to be released, so a new MAC can get a lease.